# android Webview App Crashes on Startup

Tags: android

building an app that accesses a page via webview.
but it crashes in the begining giving the following runtime error..

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.aaryansoftwares.moopl.moopl, PID: 2371
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aaryansoftwares.moopl.moopl/com.aaryansoftwares.moopl.moopl.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
                      at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
                      at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:708)
                      at com.aaryansoftwares.moopl.moopl.MainActivity.isNetworkConnected(MainActivity.java:41)
                      at com.aaryansoftwares.moopl.moopl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Application terminated.

main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(isNetworkConnected()==true)
    {
        WebView start = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        start.loadUrl("url here");
    }

    else
    {
        Intent i= new Intent(this,activityFail.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}

private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    /*ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;*/


    try {
        final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
        return !address.equals("");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // Log error
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

activityfail:

```
public class activityFail extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connection_fail);

    ImageView img =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent j=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        }
    });

}
```

}

the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aaryansoftwares.moopl.moopl">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you post your manifest file?

Comment: the manifest is posted along with athe rest

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a network call on the main thread from

> onCreate()

You must wrap your network calls in a thread.  I recommend AsyncTask for this.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do your network things here
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can also override the

> onPostExecute()

method to do any work with the UI once doInBackground calls back to the main thread.